# Newly created column in a data frame need to be updated with values based on condition ,from another column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

DF has four columns and column 'Id' in unique and it is grouped by column 'idhogar'.
column ' parentesco1' has status 0 (or) 1 . 'Target' columns has values,which  are different for various rows under same column values of 'idhogar'

```
INDEX  Id     parentesco1   idhogar Target
0   ID_fe8c32eba    0   4616164 2
1   ID_ca701e058    1   4616164 2
2   ID_5ad4372cd    0   4983866 3
3   ID_1e320689c    1   4983866 3
4   ID_700e30a8d    0   5905417 2
5   ID_bc99ecfb8    0   5905417 2
6   ID_308a05a16    1   5905417 2
7   ID_00186dde5    1   7.56E+06    4
8   ID_34570a74c    1   20713493    4
9   ID_b13870a19    1   27651991    3
10  ID_74e989389    1   45038655    4
11  ID_726ba7d34    0   60027579    4
12  ID_b75d7c648    0   60027579    4
13  ID_37e7b3aaa    1   60027579    4
14  ID_396da5a70    0   104578907   2
15  ID_4381374bb    1   104578907   2
16  ID_272a9b4d5    0   119024319   4
17  ID_1225f3779    0   119024319   4
18  ID_fc5dfaa2e    0   119024319   4
19  ID_7390a3f99    1   119024319   4
```

New column'Rev_target' created ,need to have the value of 'Target'  of row having ' parentesco1' as 1 for all the rows falling under the group of same 'idhogar'.

I tried the following but not successful.

```
for idhogar in df['idhogar'].unique():
    if len(df[df['idhogar'] == idhogar]['Target'].unique())!= 1:
        rev_target_val=df[(df['idhogar']== idhogar) & (df['parentesco1']==1)]['Target']
        df['Rev_target']=rev_target_val
        
# NOT WORKING AS REQUIRED ---- gives output as NaN in all rows  of newly created column
```

Tried the below but throwing error

```
for idhogar in df['idhogar'].unique():
    rev_target_val=df[(df['idhogar']== idhogar) & (df['parentesco1']==1)]['Target']
    df['Rev_target']=np.where(len(df[df['idhogar'] == idhogar]['Target'].unique())!= 
    1,rev_target_val,df['Target'])
```

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes () (0,) (9557,)

Tried the below but not working as intended,gives same value as 2 in all the rows of new'Rev_target' column

```
for idhogar in df['idhogar'].unique():
    rev_target_val=df[(df['idhogar']== idhogar) & (df['parentesco1']==1)]['Target']
    df['Rev_target']=df.apply(lambda x: rev_target_val if (len(df[df['idhogar'] == idhogar] 
    ['Target'].unique())!= 1) else df['Target'],axis=1)
```

Would appreciate a solution from you and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sort the dataframe on `parentesco1` in descending order to make sure that the `parentesco1` 1 row is the first row. Then a `transform` could easily access that row:

```
df['Rev_target'] = df.sort_values('parentesco1', ascending=False).groupby(
    'idhogar').transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])['Target']
```

It gives:

```
    INDEX            Id  parentesco1      idhogar  Target Rev_target
0       0  ID_fe8c32eba            0    4616164.0       2          2
1       1  ID_ca701e058            1    4616164.0       2          2
2       2  ID_5ad4372cd            0    4983866.0       3          3
3       3  ID_1e320689c            1    4983866.0       3          3
4       4  ID_700e30a8d            0    5905417.0       2          2
5       5  ID_bc99ecfb8            0    5905417.0       2          2
6       6  ID_308a05a16            1    5905417.0       2          2
7       7  ID_00186dde5            1    7560000.0       4          4
8       8  ID_34570a74c            1   20713493.0       4          4
9       9  ID_b13870a19            1   27651991.0       3          3
10     10  ID_74e989389            1   45038655.0       4          4
11     11  ID_726ba7d34            0   60027579.0       4          4
12     12  ID_b75d7c648            0   60027579.0       4          4
13     13  ID_37e7b3aaa            1   60027579.0       4          4
14     14  ID_396da5a70            0  104578907.0       2          2
15     15  ID_4381374bb            1  104578907.0       2          2
16     16  ID_272a9b4d5            0  119024319.0       4          4
17     17  ID_1225f3779            0  119024319.0       4          4
18     18  ID_fc5dfaa2e            0  119024319.0       4          4
19     19  ID_7390a3f99            1  119024319.0       4          4
```

Comment: @ Serge Ballesta     Thank you so much. I was trying group by and tried to iterate but was not successful. Deeply appreciate your efforts to solve...